# Large number of placeholders in IN() condition slows down PDO/Doctrine to a halt

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, placeholder

**The setup**

I have a query that's running with a large IN() condition. I won't get into why I have to do it this way, I know it's a bad idea, but it must be done that way.

So the raw query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN (1,2,3,4....150000)
```

**The question**

The main problem is that when I try running this query with doctrine, it creates a placeholder for each item, which is about 150,000 items. This puts a heavy load on sql to replace them, as well as PDO for some reason in fetching them. Details on that are below.

My main question is how can i use the entire array as a comma delimited list and a single replacement. It sounds easy but every way I can think of doesn't work.

**What I have done so far:**

I have all those numbers in an array: $ids

Using doctrine query builder:

```
$qb = createTheQueryBuilder('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN (:ids)');
$qb->setParameter('ids', $ids, Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
$results = $qb->execute();
$pairs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

The problem with the above method is that it creates a single ? place holder for each value. Because $ids is such a large array, this makes the query and fetching extremely slow. I'm not sure if it's a bug in the PDO drive as far as the fetching goes, but it too slow - it actually seems to stop responding completely and the php thread keeps running at 100% for hours to run $result->fetchAll()

The next thing i tried was:

```
$qb = createTheQueryBuilder('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN (:ids)');
$qb->setParameter('ids', implode(',', $ids)); ( <-- changed here )
$results = $qb->execute();
$pairs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

The problem with this is that it only returns the first result. I'm not sure how or why it's doing that.

Comment: Can you express your `IN` conditions as a subselect instead? 150,000 items in that list is pretty crazy.

Comment: If your range is every single number from 1 to 150000 you can use `col1 >= 1 AND col1 <= 150000`

Comment: Is query execution or fetching slow or both? Is col1 indexed? If you are selecting most of the rows, may be worth fetching all?

Comment: How about putting the values in a table and joining or subquery?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but that's why I didn't want to get into why I have to include them all like that. The numbers are not sequential or in any particular range. It can't be done with a subquery. It could be done with a temp table, but that would involve having a lot of temp tables because this query occurs with different inputs for different users at different times. I know we have plenty of design issues that I would love to change, but there's a bureaucracy that's going to prevent that from happening any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, you can't insert a comma delimited string into one place holder.  Be nice if you could. Instead, the only option I know of would be to insert the ids directoy into the sql and not use place holders at all.

```
$idStr = implode(',', $ids);

$qb = createTheQueryBuilder("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IN ($idStr)");
```

Obviously you should ensure that $ids has been sanitized as you have no injection protection here.

I suspect it will still be painfully slow.  Neither Doctrine nor PDO actually process the prepared statements.  It's the server that will become the bottleneck.

Comment: I actually tried this and it was incredibly fast .... compared to the other methods at least. I was hoping this wouldn't be the only way, because of the sanitization issue, but now that I think about it, it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to do that because the comma would be seen at an injection attack itself - unless the entire list were encapsulated into a string, but then it wouldn't match anything at all.